# TypeError: {variable}.style is undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typeerror

I have created a html and javascript solution to create a toggle list.

HTML is like this:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible" type="button">tryout</button>
<div class="content">lorem ipum...</div>
```

I get a notice in the console: "TypeError: content.style is undefined".

I have tried a lot but cannot figure out what i am doing wrong here...

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns  a collection

Comment: You probably should iterate through `content`

Comment: or change to `var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];`

Comment: @Addis you were right, adding [0] solves the problem!